# How can I show a button over an <img> tag on mousing over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to show a button (an image or a div with `background-image`) on another `<img>` tag when the mouse cursor gets over it. The image's width is fixed, but height can be changed.

An example of this is as follows:

[image: See image here.]

How could I do this using jQuery or pure JS?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149516/how-do-you-overlay-a-div-over-an-img-and-show-another-div-onmouseover?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    left:50%;
    z-index:1000;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("img").hover(function(){
    $("div").css("opacity",1);
},function(){
     $("div").css("opacity",0);
});
```

Work the rest yourself out.

Good tutorial: http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. Sorry, I can't rate your answer, cause my reputation is <15

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery hover method. Perhaps coupled with moving a button from off screen to the desired location. You can use css z-index to position an object above another.

Answer (score 0):

why js here ?

it is simple css:

HTML:

```
<div class="image"><div class="inner"><button>Hello</button></div></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
​.image .inner {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px;
 left: 100px;    
}
.image:hover .inner {
 display: block;   
}
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xAzT7/)

[DEMO with transition](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xAzT7/1/)

Comment: >> why js here ?
cause there are a lot of different images and I can't generate different backgrounds for all of them. Dharman helped me.

Comment: why you need generate different backgrounds ? you can set background as style. what the problem... also you can use image tag and relative div same way

Answer (score 0):

since you mentioned you want to do this using only jquery..

```
$('#buttonId').css("position", "absolute");
$('#buttonId').css("bottom","0");
$('#buttonId').css("cursor","hand");
$('#buttonId').css("cursor","pointer");
$('#buttonId').css("margin","0 auto");
$('#buttonId').parent().css("text-align","center");​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

BTW, no need of `a` tag here. If you want hand cursor then use `cursor` property.